# How to use dns.resolve4 to accept any URL input?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node JS, and needed some help in one of my implementations. I need to find a way to accept a 'any' URL as mentioned in code snippet below, but my code is not able to accept generic URLs.

Any help is appreciated.

```
dns.resolve4('www.google.com',function(err,addresses){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    if (err) { res.write(err);}
    res.write(addresses +'\n');
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: any failed URL ?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost

Comment: I want resolve4 to accept URL as a parameter instead of hardcoding address as shown in code snippet above(www.google.com)

Comment: I figured that I needed to use a variable and then, pass it to resolve4 method. :)